# MAX DATE with intermediate table

Tags: mysql, date, max

I can't get the right results. I have 4 tables:

```
table: Aluno
id_aluno    nome
1           Bruno
2           Carlos

table: Serie
id_serie    id_aluno    descricao
1           1           Tipo A
2           1           Tipo B
3           2           Tipo A

table: Treino
id_treino   id_serie    data
1           1           2015-12-10
2           2           2015-12-12
3           3           2015-12-10

table: Avaliacao
id_avaliacao   id_aluno   data_avaliacao
1              1          2015-12-07
2              1          2015-12-01
3              2          2015-12-05
4              2          2015-12-04
```

I want the following results:

```
nome     descricao    data          data_avaliacao
Bruno    TIPO B       2015-12-12    2015-12-07
Carlos   TIPO A       2015-12-10    2015-12-05
```

The problem is that the GROUP BY clause should have column "id_aluno" but it's not foreign key of the table which has the date. There is a intermediate table between them (serie). 
And I have this other table (avaliacao) which I also want the max DATE, but when I join them all, I got more than one result by aluno.

Query I tried:

```
SELECT a.nome, s.descricao, t.data, aa.data_avaliacao FROM Aluno a JOIN Serie s ON s.id_aluno = a.id_aluno JOIN Treino t ON t.id_serie = s.id_serie JOIN Avaliacao aa ON aa.id_aluno = a.id_aluno WHERE t.data = SELECT MAX(t1.data) FROM Aluno a1 JOIN Serie s1 ON s1.id_aluno = a1.id_aluno JOIN Treino t1 ON t1.id_serie = s1.id_serie WHERE s1.id_aluno = s.id_aluno )
```

Comment: SELECT
    a.nome,
    s.descricao,
    t.data, aa.data_avaliacao
FROM Aluno a
    JOIN Serie s
        ON s.id_aluno = a.id_aluno
    JOIN Treino t
        ON t.id_serie = s.id_serie
    JOIN Avaliacao aa
        ON aa.id_aluno = a.id_aluno     WHERE t.data =
                SELECT MAX(t1.data)
                FROM Aluno a1
                JOIN Serie s1
                    ON s1.id_aluno = a1.id_aluno
                JOIN Treino t1
                    ON t1.id_serie = s1.id_serie
                WHERE s1.id_aluno = s.id_aluno 
               )

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If I give you this, can you work out the other part?

```
SELECT a.nome
     , s.descricao
     , t.data
     , v.data_avaliacao
  FROM aluno a
  JOIN serie s
    ON s.id_aluno = a.id_aluno
  JOIN treino t
    ON t.id_serie = s.id_serie
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT s.id_aluno
            , MAX(t.data) max_data 
         FROM serie s 
         JOIN treino t 
           ON t.id_serie = s.id_serie 
        GROUP 
           BY id_aluno
     ) x
    ON x.id_aluno = s.id_aluno
   AND x.max_data = t.data
  JOIN avaliacao v
    ON v.id_aluno = a.id_aluno;
```

Answer (score 0):

working with your own query check out the last part, adding only the group by

```
SELECT a.nome, s.descricao, t.data, aa.data_avaliacao FROM Aluno a 
JOIN Serie s ON s.id_aluno = a.id_aluno 
JOIN Treino t ON t.id_serie = s.id_serie 
JOIN Avaliacao aa ON aa.id_aluno = a.id_aluno 

WHERE t.data = 

(SELECT MAX(t1.data) 
FROM Aluno a1 
JOIN Serie s1 ON s1.id_aluno = a1.id_aluno 
JOIN Treino t1 ON t1.id_serie = s1.id_serie 
WHERE s1.id_aluno = s.id_aluno ) group by a.nome
```

you can test it out in [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a15866/8)

Comment: It's almost what I want, but it's not bringing me the max date of avaliacao.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the code of davejal works only if coincides that in the data the MAX date of the table treino correspond to MAX date of table avaliacao for every aluno, when don´t be like that the results won´t be the expected. Using the idea of

> Strawberry

, finally would be

```
SELECT a.nome
     , s.descricao
     , t.data
     , v.data_avaliacao
  FROM aluno a
  JOIN serie s
    ON s.id_aluno = a.id_aluno
  JOIN treino t
    ON t.id_serie = s.id_serie
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT s.id_aluno
            , MAX(t.data) max_data 
         FROM serie s 
         JOIN treino t 
           ON t.id_serie = s.id_serie 
        GROUP 
           BY id_aluno
     ) x
    ON x.id_aluno = s.id_aluno
   AND x.max_data = t.data
JOIN avaliacao v
        ON s.id_aluno = v.id_aluno
WHERE v.data_avaliacao IN
   ( SELECT MAX(v.data_avaliacao) max_data1 
                FROM avaliacao v
        GROUP 
           BY id_aluno
     )
```

, hope this help